# Sublimetext 3 doesn't show german umlauts äöüß

Tags: java, utf-8, sublimetext3, javac

Sublimetext doesn't show me the German umlauts öäüß in Java when I build the program. In other program languages they work.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXHjV.png)

I've looked up just about every tutorial or post, but I can't get it to work.
Everything I know is in UTF-8. It works with Python or even when I use the Termninus addon.

I made a new build system extra Java: `{"shell_cmd": "javac -encoding utf-8 $file && java $file_base_name" }`
And I must say I like Sublime Text, I use it all the time for Python, now I want to use it for Java. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: The issue is with the console in Sublime when executing the application, not building.

Comment: How do I fix this?

Comment: I was merely clarifying your question, which incorrectly states that the problem is with "building".

Comment: I would like to add that it also works well with other programming languages such as Python, C++, etc. and with other IDEs (Visual Studio) or with the CMD. Only in Sublime Text in combination with Java